# In knitting Rmd file, print 2 plots in same row, but create separate pdfs

Tags: r, pdf, plot, rstudio

I have two plots in an Rmd file that I would like to plot side-by-side in the knitted output. I would also like to save the individual plots to separate pdfs. When I had only one plot per device, `dev.copy2pdf` worked well to avoid replotting, which I would like to do at all costs.

However, the following code yields two pdfs, neither of which is my desired output. The first pdf is the first plot on the left half of the page; the second pdf is the plots side-by-side. I understand why this is happening - after all, it is copying directly from the current device, but I'm not sure how to modify my code to achieve the result I want.

```
data(cars)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cars$Price,cars$Mileage)
dev.copy2pdf(file = "price-mileage.pdf")
plot(cars$Price,cars$Doors)
dev.copy2pdf(file = "price-doors.pdf")
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't see a way that you can do what you are asking in one step.  But you can do it without replotting in the knitr if that is what you mean.

````
```{r}
data(iris)
```

This will create your side by side plots in knitr:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Length)
```

```{r include=F}
#This will write your plots to the individual files.  
#It will not appear in the knitr because include=F
pdf("plot1.pdf")
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width)
dev.off()
pdf("plot2.pdf")
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Length)
dev.off()
```
````

Comment: I'd forgotten about the include option, thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately, the reason I'm insistent on not replotting is because of the time it takes to generate the plots, which appears to be fairly significant (it's via a custom heatmap function that a collaborator wrote).